# copy dynamic range, VBA , EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, copy, range

My datas are as shown in the picture. I want to copy ranges in column E and paste it to another sheet . how do i select a range in column "E" according to Column "D" ?.

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already got the reference in the D column, through `.Find` for example, you can copy the E portion as follows using `.Offset`.

```
range([D1],[D1].end(xldown).offset(-1)).offset(,1).copy
```

Assuming your sd value is in range D1, this will copy the values 2 to 7 from the E column.

Comment: sorry ..ur code doesnt work..y = Range([D1], [D1].End(xlDown).Offset(-1)).Offset(, 1).Address
MsgBox y
this gives me an output E1:E1048575

Comment: it will only do that if you're running it off a sheet that doesn't have anything below cell D1. With your example, my solution works (except for the last block, I'll agree to that).